# Swift switch statements need to be exhaustive?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

The switch construct in Swift needs to be exhaustive, which is usually satisfied by having a default branch. My question is, is a default branch always required? It seems to be the case, or I'm misunderstanding something with this:

```
let x: Bool = false;

switch x { 
  case true: 
    println("true") 
  case false: 
    println("false")
}
```

The above fails with "error: switch must be exhaustive, consider adding a default clause" but since Bool has only two possible values "true" and "false", isn't that exhaustive already?

Comment: The Asker never accepted an answer but there's one with 14 up-votes.